# Compile Dart for Android

Tags: android, dart

How can I compile a Dart program to run on an Android device? According to https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile, only MacOS, Windows, and Linux are supported and there's no cross-compilation support.

Comment: You can use Flutter to run your dart code. Because in Android a basic GUI needs to be there to run anything

Comment: @gtxtreme what about a command-line program?

Comment: Does your Command Line Program not have input parameters? You can have them from the user in a textfield
Flutter would be great even then. You can have a button to start stop your cli procesd

Comment: @gtxtreme Hmm I'm just trying to get a hello world to run in adb shell. Is there no way to run Dart without Flutter on Android?

Comment: I don't know a way without using Flutter